# Selecting Elements from a 3-D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have a numpy `array` called data that has shape `(512,3)`, for which I have assigned the names `x,y,z` for each column. I have 3 predefined values, say `x_0`, `y_0` and `z_0`.

I want 3 new arrays where only those values of `x`, `y`, and `z` will be appended which satisfy the condition that `sqrt((x_0-x)^2+(y_0-y)^2+(z_0-z)^2) <= 2000`.

Can anyone kindly suggest some solution?

Comment: Where is the data? Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

Given this random array with your preset dimensions:

```
myArray = np.random.rand(512,3) * 1000
```

When you are slicing numpy arrays you can either do that via indexing:

```
myNewArray = myArray[100:120,1:3]
```

or even with conditions. For instance, if you want to get rid of all values higher than 500, you'd go:

```
myNewArray = myArray[myArray<=500]
```

(reading: Create myNewArray by checking myArray and taking only those entries for which myArray is smaller or equal to 500).

In your case, the condition is a bit more complicated, but the logic is the same:

for ...

```
x_0 = 1000
y_0 = 1500
z_0 = 2000

myNewArray = myArray[np.sqrt((x_0 - myArray[:,0])**2 + (y_0 - myArray[:,1])**2 + (z_0 - myArray[:,2])**2) <= 2000]
```

... `myArray` in my random case was filtered such that `myNewArray` turned out to be of shape `(286L, 3L)`. They are only those entries that met the condition.

(I used column indexing instead of names x, y, z to avoid confusion with x_0, y_0 and z_0)

Comment: That's good. Please try and understand what I did and if it worked for you, please mark the answer as accepted (i.e. question solved).